# opencv python compute second moments of a set of contours

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'd like to perform the calculation of the second moments and volume fraction of an image which has a great number of contours.
I've been studying the cv2.findcontours function and also cv2.connectedComponents in order to solve my problem, without success.
This is the target image : [image with a huge number of contours](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/710615/testLayer6_.png) , but I create the image bellow to be an example:[image: image as example]
For instance on the triangle 1 its volume fraction it's none, and it's moments 0; on the triangle 2, its volume fraction is 100% and its moments max, on the triangle 3, probably 30% of volume fraction and its moments unknown, and so on for all triangles.

I think that will be useful use the [image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/710615/new_refined2__DXF.png) which contains the triangles only, an then use both .
If I use findCountour I'll get all the contours, and not only the triangles.
If I use connectedComponents I don't get all the triangles.
I'll just put here a litle bit of code, but I think this is not important, my major difficulty it's the problem approach.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cv2
import numpy as np

imMesh = cv2.imread('testLayer6_.png', -1)
imTriangles = cv2.imread('new_refined2__DXF.png', -1)

imGrayMsh = cv2.cvtColor(imMesh, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(thresh, imMesh_bw) = cv2.threshold(imGrayMsh, 128, 255,
                                  cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
imGrayTri = cv2.cvtColor(imTriangles, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, imTri_bw = cv2.threshold(imGrayTri, 250, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
connectivity = 4
output = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(imTri_bw, connectivity, cv2.CV_32S)
num_labels = output[0]
labels = output[1]
stats = output[2]
centroids = output[3]

_, contours, hier_ = cv2.findContours(imTri_bw, cv2.RETR_TREE,
                                  cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

I hope that you can help me solve this problem !